# Facebook keeps asking about accepting cookies on all browsers

Tags: login, firefox, google-chrome, facebook, cookie

I'm trying to login into [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) and the website is constantly asking me to accept cookies. When I click "accept all", the page refreshes, popup window appears again and some string is being appended to the URL, so after few tries it looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin%2F%3Fnext%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Flogin%252F%253Fnext%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.facebook.com%25252F
```

This issue is reproducible across all browsers I've tested (chrome, firefox, opera) and persists after reboot. I can accept cookies and login into mobile version of the facebook webpage, but, after that, when trying to access desktop version, I am asked to do it again. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I tried many solutions from the internet (f. e. switching to strict protection, clearing cache), but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Do you have any kind of ad blockers enabled?  Ad blockers *typically* block external media like those cookie notification things, so temporarily disabling your protection and blockers will allow you to accept, then you just re-enable them.

Comment: No, I do not have any blockers among all of the browsers I've currently installed on my PC.